# Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am not able to start a new project in eclipse.  Every time I go for new Android project it gives the warning "SDK target must be specified" and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: That sounds like a 1007 STOP SHOUTING error to me.

Comment: Purchase new keyboard which have caps lock off functionality seems like everything is in caps lock question, name etc.

Answer (score 4):

- At first you need to download Android SDK, and decompress.
- You will need to install Eclipse ADT plugin

Then (from the android website)
   1.  Select Window > Preferences...  to open the Preferences panel (Mac OS X: Eclipse > Preferences).
   2. Select Android from the left panel.
   3. For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your downloaded SDK directory.
   4. Click Apply, then OK.

Thats all

Reference:

install:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

configure:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Answer (score 1):

"Target must be specified" means that you need to select the correct Android version from the big list in the New Project window.